# "Variable" not accessed

Tags: python, function, blackjack

I'm working on a Blackjack program and everything works fine except my `PlayAgain()` function. In this function, im supposed to reset my variables but when i do so, the variables are discolored in a darker blue and when hovered over, it says "variable" is not accessed. When running the program and trying to play again, the variables are still left with the previous values. I'm pretty new to python so I have no idea how to deal with this, help would be nice.

[image: here is the issue]

here is my ENTIRE code:

```
import random

deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]*4
dealer = []
hand = []
random.shuffle(deck)

def DealDealer(deck):
    while len(dealer) < 2:
        card = deck.pop()
        if card == 11:card = "J"
        if card == 12:card = "Q"
        if card == 13:card = "K"
        if card == 14:card = "A"
        dealer.append(card)
    return dealer

def DealPlayer(deck):
    while len(hand) < 2:
        card = deck.pop()
        if card == 11:card = "J"
        if card == 12:card = "Q"
        if card == 13:card = "K"
        if card == 14:card = "A"
        hand.append(card)
    return hand

def PlayAgain():
    again = input("\nDo you want to play again? (Y/N) : ").lower()
    if again == "y":
        Game()
        deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]*4
        dealer = []
        hand = []
        random.shuffle(deck)
    else:
        print("Bye!")
        exit()

def Hit():
    card = deck.pop()
    if card == 11:card = "J"
    if card == 12:card = "Q"
    if card == 13:card = "K"
    if card == 14:card = "A"
    hand.append(card)
    return hand

def DealerHit():
    card = deck.pop()
    if card == 11:card = "J"
    if card == 12:card = "Q"
    if card == 13:card = "K"
    if card == 14:card = "A"
    dealer.append(card)
    return dealer

def HandTotal(hand):
    total = 0
    for card in hand:
        if(card == "J" or card == "Q" or card == "K"):
            total+= 10
        elif(card == "A"):
            if(total >= 11):
                total+= 1
            else: 
                total+= 11
        else:
            total += card
    return total

def DealerTotal(dealer):
    total = 0
    for card in dealer:
        if(card == "J" or card == "Q" or card == "K"):
            total+= 10
        elif(card == "A"):
            if(total >= 11):
                total+= 1
            else: 
                total+= 11
        else:
            total += card
    return total

def DealersRetribution():
    while(DealerTotal(dealer) < HandTotal(hand)):
        DealerHit()
        print("Dealer's Hand: ", dealer)

        if(DealerTotal(dealer) > 21):
            print("\Dealer Busted! You Win!\nYour Score: ", HandTotal(hand), "\nDealer's Score: ", DealerTotal(dealer))
            PlayAgain()
    
def Score():
    if(HandTotal(hand) == DealerTotal(dealer)):
        print("\nTie! I'll getcha next time!\nYour Score: ", HandTotal(hand), "\nDealer's Score: ", DealerTotal(dealer))
    elif(HandTotal(hand) > DealerTotal(dealer)):
        print("What?! You Won?! How?! U Just got lucky.\nYour Score: ", HandTotal(hand), "\nDealer's Score: ", DealerTotal(dealer))
    else:
        print("\nYou Lose!\nYour Score: ", HandTotal(hand), "\nDealer's Score: ", DealerTotal(dealer))

def NormalAction():
    action = input("\nHit - press 1\nStand - press 2\nDouble Down - press 3\n> ")
    if(action == "1"):
        Hit()
        print("\nDealer's Hand: ", dealer)
        print("Your Hand: ", hand)
        if(HandTotal(hand) > 21):
            print("\nYou Busted!\nYour Score: ", HandTotal(hand), "\nDealer's Score: ", DealerTotal(dealer))
            PlayAgain()
        else:
            NormalAction()
    elif(action == "2"):
        print()
        DealersRetribution()
        print("\nDealer's Hand: ", dealer)
        print("Your Hand: ", hand)
        Score()
    elif(action == "3"):
        Hit()
        print("\nDealer's Hand: ", dealer)
        print("Your Hand: ", hand)
        DealersRetribution()
        print("\nDealer's Hand: ", dealer)
        print("Your Hand: ", hand)
        Score()
    else:
        print("\nPlease enter a correct action (1/2)!")
        NormalAction()

def Game():
    play = input("\nWELCOME TO BLACKJACK!\nPlay - press 1\nQuit - press 2\n> ")
    if(play == "2"):
        print("\nBye, Have a nice day!")
        exit()
    elif(play == "1"):
        DealDealer(deck)
        DealPlayer(deck)
        print("\nDealer's Hand: ", dealer[0], "X")
        print("Your Hand: ", hand)
        NormalAction()
        PlayAgain()
    else:
        print("\nPlease enter a correct action (1/2)!")
        Game()

Game()
```

Thx in advance.

ps: I've been trying to get splitting(blackjack splitting, not programming splitting) to work but have no idea how to go about it. I originally thought that i could just make an array inside an array but quickly realized that caused all sorts of problems. Help on this would also be nice but the Error is the main issue right now

edit: a request for where i defined my variables were ask. I defined them at the very top of my program.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2vxt.png)

Comment: The variables in your function don't have any relation to anything outside the function, so the values you're assigning to them are never used for anything.  You probably want to make these instance attributes of an object and have the function be an instance method that can modify the attributes.

Comment: if you want to assign global variables you have to declare them global  in *PlayAgain*, so `global deck, dealer, hand`  in *PlayAgain* before to assign them. Currently you assign local variables. Of course an other way is to give them in argument to *Game*, avoid global variables when you can

Comment: @Samwise i suspected that these values were never used so I tried to put a return statement earlier but that didnt work because i am also calling a function. About the rest of your comment, I see a lot of big words that i am not entirely sure what they mean. I know what objects, attributes and methods are but im not too sure what an instance is. Could you maybe give me an example on how i would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the value is shuffled in the play again function, but not in the Game() function.

What you probably should do is this:

```
def PlayAgain():
    again = input("\nDo you want to play again? (Y/N) : ").lower()
    if again == "y":
         Game()
    else:
         print("Bye!")
         exit()
```

---

And implement this part in the beginning of your Game() function:

```
def Game():       
        deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]*4
        dealer = []
        hand = []
        random.shuffle(deck)
        #rest_of_your_code
```

If this does not work you should also share your Game() function ;)

Comment: This solution was half correct. turns out that i needed to add them as global inside Game() or it would give me 40 more errors 

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

That is because vs-code detect that code as **deadcode** which is not going to be used in the program.
It will get more clear from the example below:

```
 b = "hello"
 def abc():
   a = input('enter first number')
   return a
 abc()
```

In the example above, b is never used, so it is detected as **deadcode** by vs-code. So vs code refer these statements as **not accessible**.*But the code will still get executed.*

In your case , dealer is not used in the program so vs-code finds it as deadcode

Comment: This resolved my question. Thank you!